# jQuery: One sortable list, display results on another list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI Sortable to make a list sortable. I also have another list that is not sortable, that i want to update when i sort the sortable list, so that it displays the same order as the sortable list.

The items in the display_only list will contain input fields, so ideally the items in "display_only" should also move in the DOM, but not an requirement.

I have tried just about everything that i can come up with, like detaching the element and trying to reinsert it at it's new order and so on, but i can't really figure it out. Anything that would lead me in the right direction would be great!

**Example HTML:**

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li data-id="1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-id="2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-id="3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="display_only">
    <li data-id="1">Item 1 and som other content</li>
    <li data-id="2">Item 2 and som other content</li>
    <li data-id="3">Item 3 and som other content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe add a function like this to your `stop` event in the sortable? `stop: function(){
 var sourceHtml = $('#sortable').html();
 $('#display_only').html(sourceHtml).find('li').append('<input />');
}`

Answer (score 6):

There's no real need to use arrays here. But, you can easily integrate defining array items among this.

```
 $('#sortable').sortable({
        start: function(event, ui){
                iBefore = ui.item.index();
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
                iAfter = ui.item.index();
                evictee = $('#display_only li:eq('+iAfter+')');
                evictor = $('#display_only li:eq('+iBefore+')');

                evictee.replaceWith(evictor);
                if(iBefore > iAfter)
                    evictor.after(evictee);
                else
                    evictor.before(evictee);
        }
 });
```

I'm sure writing it into a function and passing the parent selectors as args is more suitable though.

Answer (score 1):

what about using the $.fn.clone() method to clone the sorted ul
and triggring a clone everytime you sort with

```
$('#sortable').bind('sort', function(e,ui){
   $newlist = $(this).clone();

   $('#display_only').remove();   //removing the old list
   $newlist.attr('id','display_only'); // giving the right id for the cloned element
   $(this).append($newlist)

});
```

notice I'm not sure about the exact syntax, that yours to research, but I think this should work

notice that jquery ui sortable has a bunch of events and you should bind the right one for you [jquery ui sortable events](http://jqueryui.it/demos/sortable#events) I suspect 'stop', 'beforeStop' or 'change' would be the right one

another edit and solution might be: just sorting the other list after the first one is sorted, automaticaly with event binding like:

```
$('#sortable').bind('sort', function(e,ui){
   $("#display_only).sortable()

});
```

simple and elegent

Comment: That was on the right track, but not quite there. I can't get the list in "#display_only" to reorder according to the #sortable list. Please keep in mind that "#display_only" contains other content than #sortable, so i can't just clone that list. 

I have one idea, and that is to use maybe serialize() to get the new order, and somehow reindex "#display_only".

I currently use stop, but update should work aswell.

Comment: ah I didn't realize the display_only list is with different data from the original list. I see you already found a solution for that. Notice that if the only difference is the input fields  inside the li you could still use the clone and than iterate through the list and add the input files accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit if tweaking i got it working. I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve it, but it works. On stop i call my function to reorder the items in "#display_ only", that loops through the new order, and pushes that into an array.

After that i loop through my items in "#display_only" and detach them in the same order, and then just appends them to my list, like this:

```
function reorder() {
    var newOrder = [];
    $('#sortable li').each(function(i) {
         newOrder.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    });
    $('#display_only li').each(function(i) {
         var item = $("li[data-id="+newOrder[i]+"]").detach();
         $('#display_only').append(item);
    });
}
```

Comment: actually there are many problem with this solution. but the main one is that I don't think this would work the right way.. consider both list are:b,d,c,a and after the sort the first one is a,b,c,d . then you'll take the a element data-id and add it to the b element in the second list..